# InvalidUseOfMatchersException: not using any raw values

Tags: java, mockito, hamcrest

I don't know what's causing this issue, but it throws an InvalidUseOfMatchersException.

```
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
//incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
//correct:
someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

The code that causes the exception is below.

```
when(EventHandlingForFileUpload.onUploadEvent(any(CustomBatchFile.class))).thenReturn(SomeCustomEvents);
```

Comment: Strange. Maybe you could add the signature of that method `onUploadEvent()` that you intend to test there. And the line that actually calls that method from your production code.

Answer (score 0):

If `EventHandlingForFileUpload.onUploadEvent` is a static method, then you'll need to [use PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) or refactor your code; Mockito only works for non-`final` instance methods on non-`final` classes and interfaces (without [Mockito 2.1's opt-in final-mocking magic](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable)).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the method isn't static and it isn't final, nor is the class final.

Comment: @user3822332 Ah! Be aware that your naming (`EventHandlingForFileUpload`) is unusual for Java instances. I'd recommend posting the code for `onUploadEvent` as well as the code surrounding the exception line--particularly the lines immediately before it. Mockito matchers are stateful, so it can be deceptive which line is actually a misuse of Mockito.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I'm afraid I can't post any more of it as it is proprietary. :(

Comment: Then look into creating a [mcve] for us. Simply create a faked non proprietary example that shows your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was also not using any raw values but got "InvalidUseOfMatchersException"

I had something like

```
when(service.getResolver(eq(document.getId()), anyString())).thenReturn(aResolver);
```

and it was throwing the exception. "document" is a mock

After I changed it to ...

```
when(service.getResolver(eq(docId), anyString())).thenReturn(aResolver);
```

... it worked (i.e. I moved out the method call getId())